# Dividing a point by a specific number in elliptic curve

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve

There is a elliptic curve with parameters:

```
a = 0xb3b04200486514cb8fdcf3037397558a8717c85acf19bac71ce72698a23f635
b = 0x12f55f6e7419e26d728c429a2b206a2645a7a56a31dbd5bfb66864425c8a2320
```

Also the prime number is:

```
q = 0x247ce416cf31bae96a1c548ef57b012a645b8bff68d3979e26aa54fc49a2c297
```

How can I solve the equation `P * 65537 = H` and obtain the value of P?

P and H are points and H equals to `(72782057986002698850567456295979356220866771008308693184283729159903205979695, 7766776325114464021923523189912759786515131109431296018171065280757067869793)`.

Note that in the equation we have [Elliptic curve point multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication)!

Comment: 16 point doublings and one addition. Please keep in mind that this is probably too broad for the Stack Exchange Q&A format. A good beginners book on elliptic curves should give you an idea how exactly you calculate it.

Comment: It looks like you must solve an elliptic curve discrete log to get P, no? If the parameters are too big, this won't be feasible.

Comment: I don't think it is ECDLP, because ECDLP assumes that the points are public and the scalar is secret.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the number of points on the curve to solve this.  Let's call that number `n`.  Then you will have to compute the inverse of 65537 modulo `n` and do a scalar multiply of your point `H` by that number.